# asyncio running three times slower. What's wrong with my code?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

```
# _*_ coding: utf-8 _*_

import asyncio
from pprint import pprint
import time

async def add(a, b, c): return a+b+c
async def concat(a, b): return a+b
async def even(l): return [x for x in l if not x%2]
async def split(s): return s.split()
async def int_list(s): return [int(c) for c in s]

d = {   add:(3,4,5), 
        concat:('Lill', 'Klas'),
        even:[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]],
        split:['ett två tre fyra'],
        int_list:['12345']
    }

async def run(dic):
    return {k.__name__:await asyncio.gather(k(*v,)) for k, v in dic.items()}

start=time.perf_counter()
res = asyncio.run(run(d))
end=time.perf_counter()

pprint(res)
print(end-start)
```

The code is running three times slower than without the async. And I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.
I am running python 3.10.5.

no async:       0.00033
async           0.00098

Comment: If you want to check the speed, do more than almost nothing. Get into the seconds at least.

Comment: @HEllRZA: Adding a `for i in range(1000):` around the one timed line actually makes the differences more obvious; it's roughly a factor of 100 difference. That said, structuring it that way means you are setting up and tearing down the event loop every time, which is a huge overhead expense you'd never pay in real `asyncio` code.

Comment: Side-note: The pointless `gather` call (you only have one thing to `await`, so `gather` does nothing) is responsible for nearly a third of the time of the `async` code. You seem to be going out of your way to make the code slower.

Comment: You got a good answer now below. What I actually meant was: do more work in your asynchronous thread, not almost nothing.

Answer (score 2):

`async` functions involve setting up a separate call stack for each of the tasks (similar to generator functions). The functions you've written are *extremely* lightweight, so the overhead of making them async is extreme.

It's unclear why you're even using `asyncio` here; `asyncio.gather` won't "parallelize" anything that doesn't ultimately devolve to low level I/O of some kind (it's not multithreading, so all it can do is schedule I/O and do other stuff while waiting for it; the best it can do for parallelism is wrap parallel task dispatch with `run_in_executor`, which has its own overhead). Add-on the work to launch the event loop, create and queue the tasks, extract their results, and in a program with so little actual work to be done, the `asyncio` overhead exceeds that of the real work. Practically speaking, what you've written is 100% synchronous, you just added a bunch of rigmarole to handle it *as if* it were asynchronous, without actually using any of those features.

In short: **Don't use `asyncio` when your code is not in any way asynchronous. Don't time execution of trivial amounts of code wrapped in expensive overhead that real programs never pay (e.g. repeatedly creating, running, tearing down, and destroying an event loop, which is what `asyncio.run` does for you, or calling `asyncio.gather` once per call, when `gather` exists solely to simultaneously `await` multiple tasks).**